# itertools.islice does not advance iterator in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
seq = 'abcdefghijklmn'

for i in itertools.islice(enumerate(seq), 2, 5):        
        print(i)

#(2, 'c')
#(3, 'd')
#(4, 'e')     

for i in itertools.islice(enumerate(seq), 3, 4):        
        print(i)


#(3, 'd')
```

but the expected result from the second for loop should be:

```
#(8, 'i')
```

Why the enumerate(seq) was not advanced after the first loop?

Comment: Both your examples have `for i in itertools.islice(enumerate(a), 2, 5)` - can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50165733/edit) with the code you ran.

Comment: Where do you define `a`?

Comment: Why do you expect two identical code fragments to produce different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the generator anew every time, by calling `enumerate`.

If you work on the same generator, it advances as expected.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> seq = "abcdefghijklmnop"
>>> gen = enumerate(seq)
>>> list(itertools.islice(gen, 3))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
>>> list(itertools.islice(gen, 3))
[(3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')]
>>> list(itertools.islice(gen, 3))
[(6, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i')]
>>> _
```